# AWS S3 upload fails: RequestTimeTooSkewed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using

> aws s3 sync ~/folder/ s3:// --delete

to upload (and sync) a large number of files to an S3 bucket. Some - but not all - of the files fail, throwing this error message:

> upload failed:  to s3://bucketname/folder/
>   A client error (RequestTimeTooSkewed) occurred when calling the UploadPart operation: The difference between the request time and the current time is too large

I know that the cause of this error is usually a local time that's out of sync with Internet time, but I'm running NTP (on my Ubuntu PC) and the date/time seem absolutely accurate - and this error has only been reported for about 15 out of the forty or so files I've uploaded so far.
Some of the files are relatively large - up to about 70MB each - and my upload speeds aren't fantastic: could S3 possibly be comparing the initial and completion times and reporting their difference as an error?
Thanks,

Comment: It doesn't matter how long your upload takes as S3 uses only the Date (or x-amz-date) header to compare times and it does not rely on the upload completion time.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It now seems that multipart uploads were failing on aws s3. Using s3cmd instead works perfectly.

Answer (score 42):

The time verification happens at the start of your upload to S3, so it won't be to do with files taking too long to upload.

Try comparing your system time with what S3 is reporting and see if there is any unnecessary time drift, just to make sure:

```
# Time from Amazon
$ curl http://s3.amazonaws.com -v

# Time on your local machine
$ date -u
```

(Time is returned in UTC)

Comment: Thanks. I was only two seconds off...and that's with running the two commands one after the other.

Comment: Faced this issue using Homestead laravel with vagrant difference was about 15minutes :O .... Did vagrant halt and vagrant up seems to be working fine after that... One of my junior had to restart the computer which worked for him.

Comment: And how to fix it then?

Answer (score 15):

I was running `aws s3 cp` inside docker container on a MacBook Pro and got this error. Restart the Docker for Mac fixed this issue.

Answer (score 13):

Amazon S3 uses NTP for its system clocks, to sync with your clock.
Run

`sudo apt-get install ntp`

then open `/etc/ntp.conf` and add at the bottom

```
server 0.amazon.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 1.amazon.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 2.amazon.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 3.amazon.pool.ntp.org iburst
```

Then run

`sudo service ntp restart`

Comment: works perfect. One small point - I have to use `sudo service ntp restart`

Comment: This does not match the local time with the aws time..but seems to work correctly. Can you please explain in 1-2 lines how your solution works?

Answer (score 4):

You have to sync you local time on your machine. The time is out of world time.

Comment: Restarting the virtual machine worked for me. Not sure why it was not synced, but maybe is this happening when suspending the machine, rather than turning it down?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the issue on MacOS.
I fixed it by 
Preference -> Date & Time -> check the box "Set date and time automatically"

Answer (score 1):

If you have Windows, uncheck into control panel, Date & Time the "Adjust for daylight saving time automatically".

it works for me,

:D[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07AYy.png)

Comment: Along the same lines... I had the time on my Mac manually set different from my timezone, and this caused boto to fail uploads/downloads to my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Running a large number of S3 queries in parallel can cause this, as a result of how JavaScript deals with concurrency. The requests, including date headers, are all prepared quickly, but are then executed gradually, resulting in increasing clock skews.

**Solution in brief:** Break up your requests into smaller chunks with something like lodash `chunk` and await each chunk of requests before proceeding to the next.

### Explanation

JavaScript is primarily single-threaded, using an event-driven, non-blocking concurrency model. Node.js spawns separate threads for specific tasks like timers (setTimeout, setInterval) and low-level I/O operations such as `http.request` to achieve concurrency. However, the main execution remains single-threaded. When you create 1000 S3 requests inside `await Promise.all()`, what happens is this:

1. Request 0 gets constructed, which involves an HTTP PUT request with a Date header set to the current system time. Then it reaches the low-level I/O operation `http.request()`, which spawns a thread to deal with this, and the call stack is placed on the JavaScript's callback queue. So far, this has taken a few nanoseconds.
2. Query 1 gets constructed, and its Date header is set to essentially the same time, perhaps +1 millisecond. Again, the call stack gets placed on the callback queue once it reaches the low-level I/O.
3. And so on...

All 1000 requests are prepared and queued very quickly, within a few milliseconds. Some time later, the first I/O operation completes. The number of concurrent requests is limited by factors including connection pool size, which is typically set to a maximum of 5 by NodeJS. So only a few requests are running at a time, and all the remainer have to wait their turn. If you have many long-running requests then it's entirely possible that by the time the last one is received by the S3 server it's already more than 15 minutes past the Date specified in that request's header. I beliexe most S3 servers will respond with the error you've seen if clock skew exceeds 15 minutes.

By using `chunk` and awaiting each chunk before moving on to the next, you reduce the delay between requests being generated and the last request in the chunk actually being sent.

Comment: this one should be marked as the right answer, especially when the app "hangs" due to a heavy unoptimized task and thus produces this issue with time differences. 
thank you Ben for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the machine fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

In cmd
Give aws configure
Set your default region name = us-east-1

Whatever it may be but there should be any ,
But not none

Default region name [none] -->> ×××××
Default region name [us-east-1] -->> √√

Create a bucket via GUI in the aws website and check its the time of creation
In the creation date

Note down that date and time  from aws

and set the date and time of your pc with as same (which you have noted down)from settings in your pc

And now try to give the command in cmd
-> aws s3 ls